# Error Reading Data into Arrays in Java

Tags: java

I created a method that puts the read numbers into a `NumberArray` and in total 2 `NumberArrays` are created per input file. I have created an array of the object `NumberRow` on the line I marked with "!!!!". I put the read double into the array. However, when I read those arrays, `numberRow[0]` is not correct; all the values belonging in `numberRow[1]` are in there, and the values in `numberRow[1]` are correct. There is probably a simple solution, but I really don't see what is going wrong here.

```
Unit[] unitArray = new Unit[dataset.numberOfRecords];
    double[] emptyDoubleArray = new double[dataset.numberOfRecords];
    for(int x = 0; x<dataset.numberOfVariables; x++){
        numberRow[x] = new NumberRow(emptyDoubleArray);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<dataset.numberOfRecords; i++){
        String label = in.next();
        double[] elementsPerUnit = new double[dataset.numberOfVariables];
        for(int k = 0; k<dataset.numberOfVariables; k++){
            double misc = in.nextDouble();
        !!!!!   numberRow[k].NumberArray[i] = misc;
            elementsPerUnit[k] = misc;
        }
        unit = new Unit(label, elementsPerUnit);
        unitArray[i] = unit;
    }
    unitRow = new UnitRow(unitArray);
    out.print(Arrays.toString(numberRow[0].NumberArray));
}
```

Comment: The above code is virtually impossible to follow.  You've left out far too much context (and also left out all the comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are objects in Java. That is, they are not copied and passed by value (like `int`, etc), they are passed by reference (like Object, String...)

If you create an array with `new` and pass it to two objects, there is still only one array (you only used `new` once, think about it this way). When one object edits the array, the single copy of the array, having been edited, 's edits are seen by the other object.

The solution is, create a new array if it should be distinct from all other arrays.

EDIT: You create one array here (note the `new`)

```
double[] emptyDoubleArray = new double[dataset.numberOfRecords];
```

this one array is passed to all NumberRows (note, no `new`)

```
numberRow[x] = new NumberRow(emptyDoubleArray);
```

therefore if I edit any NumberRow's array it is seen in all NumberRows.

Comment: But am I not doing this here? 
for(int x = 0; x<dataset.numberOfVariables; x++){
        numberRow[x] = new NumberRow(emptyDoubleArray);
    }

Comment: That isn't creating an array, it's creating a NumberRow object.

Comment: Oh wait, I see, thank you very much ! I put the empty double array in the for loop, creating two seperate ones.